# Object's Property Activates Function When Changed?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, properties

I have an object, in this example a ferrari. When the speed changes using `ferrari.speed = 90;`, say, I would like for this property to do something about the change, for example changing the speed of an onscreen ferrari using a function.

I would like to know what's the simplest, least crazy way of doing this?

Here's a jsfiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/qhV7B/3/

```
<button id="addspeed">speed up!!</button>
<button id="checkspeed">Check the speed!</button>


function car(){
    speed: 0;
    //Do something about speed change here? if its changed at all, greater or smaller?
}
document.getElementById('addspeed').onclick = function speedchange(){
    ferrari.speed++;
}
document.getElementById('checkspeed').onclick = function checkspeed() {
    alert(ferrari.speed);
}
var ferrari = new car();
ferrari.speed = 10;
```

Comment: Use a function instead ie `ferrari.setSpeed(90)` there you can perform any other functions necessary.

Comment: May be of interest: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/

Comment: @asawyer I kind of want to use the traditional method though. `ferrari.speed = 90;`

Comment: @lawm I have no idea what you mean by "Traditional method" in this context. You want `for this property to do something about the change` right? How do you propose to accomplish this with a simple field?

Comment: That's...err..the question! I set the speed functionless, and when this happens, a function is fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set operator` is what you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set

Here is my solution http://jsfiddle.net/qhV7B/6/.

```
function car(){
}

car.prototype = {
    hidden_speed: 0,
    set speed(v){
        //special action
        alert("I changed value to " + v);
        this.hidden_speed = v;
    },
    get speed(v){
        return this.hidden_speed;
    },
};

var ferrari = new car();
ferrari.speed = 10;

document.getElementById('addspeed').onclick = function speedchange(){
    ferrari.speed = (ferrari.speed + 1);
}
document.getElementById('checkspeed').onclick = function checkspeed() {
    alert(ferrari.speed);
}
```

Comment: This solution is cleaner, though depending on the target browsers it won't work - from Mozilla's docs: `No support (notably in IE6-8) means that the script will trigger a syntax error.`

Comment: Same thing for [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) : a possible solution, but not implemented on all major browsers. That's why people still stick with the `ferrari.setSpeed()` solution.

Comment: Well... who cares of IE < 9?:)

Comment: My objection is more practical - It makes the code harder to read and understand from a maintenance point of view. A function call as seen from the calling code is clear, seeing a field set you would have no way of knowing what side effects could be happening. It's a bug-nest.

Comment: The thing is, I wouldn't use this for a one time thing. It would be sort of a library and making it dynamic is important to me.

Comment: @ProblemFactory , is `function car(){}` not necessary? Can I eliminate this block in favor of your `car.prototype`? Also, how easy is it to add more properties like this to the `car` object?

Comment: @lawm `function car(){}` (empty in this case) is necessary, `prototype` is part of `function` object. More properties to your car class you could easy add in `prototype` object, of course!

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! I realize now that it makes sense more to use a function, but as this answers my original question, I have marked this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done via getters and setters, one way is via Object.defineProperty():

```
function car(){
    this._speed=0;
}
...
var ferrari = new car();
Object.defineProperty(car.prototype,"speed",{
    get:function(){return this._speed;},
    set:function(v){
        this._speed=v;
        document.getElementById("speed").textContent=v.toString(10);
    }
});
ferrari.speed = 10;
```

modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhV7B/7/) <strike>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhV7B/5/)</strike>.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Other documentation on getters and setters which may or may not be obsolete and/or platform dependent:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineSetter

* edit: changed parameter of `Object.defineProperty` from `ferrari` to `car.prototype`

Comment: This doesn't really work for me, as I'm looking for something to work with the car object itself, not ferrari specifically. Like, I could have a million different cars. Thanks anyway, though!

Comment: @lawm  In that case change to `Object.defineProperty(car.prototype,...);`.  and [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhV7B/7/).

Answer (score 0):

This code uses a `setSpeed` method that will allow you to add any other logic needed when the speed changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/rujbX/2/

```
var Car, ferrari,
  __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };

Car = (function() {
  function Car() {
    this.setSpeed = __bind(this.setSpeed, this);
  }

  Car.prototype.speed = 0;

  Car.prototype.setSpeed = function(newSpeed) {
    this.speed = newSpeed;
    //Here is where you custom logic needs to run
    return alert("Speed Changed to: " + this.speed);
  };

  return Car;

})();

ferrari = new Car();

ferrari.setSpeed(10);

document.getElementById('addspeed').onclick = function speedchange(){
    ferrari.setSpeed(ferrari.speed+1);
}
document.getElementById('checkspeed').onclick = function checkspeed() {
    alert(ferrari.speed);
}
```

[The Javascript was generated here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Car%0A%20%20speed%3a%200%0A%20%20setSpeed%3a%20%28newSpeed%29%20=%3E%0A%20%20%20%20@speed%20=%20newSpeed%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%22Speed%20Changed%20to%3a%20#%7B@speed%7D%22%0A%0A%0Aferrari%20=%20new%20Car%28%29%0Aferrari.setSpeed%2810%29;)

Comment: Like I said in Evan's answer, I'm looking to set the ferrari's speed with setting the actual property, not using a function. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Using asawyers suggestion in the comments you can create a speedUp function which can trigger your animation function on change (or speedChange if you want to be able to slow down, whatever floats your boat).

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/86HtX/

I also made a couple adjustments on your code there:

```
function car(){
    var car = this;

    this.speed = 0;

    this.speedUp = function(mph){
         car.speed += mph;
         car.animate();
    };

    this.animate = function(){
         alert(car.speed); // new speed
    };

    //Do something about speed change here? if its changed at all, greater or smaller?
}

document.getElementById('addspeed').onclick = function speedchange(){
    ferrari.speedUp(1); // go 1 mph faster
}

document.getElementById('checkspeed').onclick = function checkspeed() {
    alert(ferrari.speed);
}

var ferrari = new car();
ferrari.speed = 10;
```

Comment: I'm looking to interact with the object using `ferrari.speed = 10;` though. And then that would be detected... Your approach uses a function, however, bypassing the point. If I were to `ferrari.speed = 11` in the code, nothing would happen in your case.